# Microsoft Graph|: How to send Email with Custom Sender Name before Email address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was wondering if there is a way to send emails using Graph APIs but with a custom sender name; By default sender Name is being displayed the username of **email sender (From)** like below:

**test    < test@domain.com >**

Sometimes we want to use same sender email but display different names based on the country we're sending email to, like below:

**test country A    < testA@domain.com >**

**test country B    < testA@domain.com >**

**test country C    < testA@domain.com >**

how is that possible with Graph APIs? below is the json used:

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Test from API",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Html",
      "content": "Hello, this is a test made with attachments: <br/> txt file"
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "myEmail@Domain.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "attachments": [
      {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "name": "attachment.txt",
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "contentBytes": "SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhClRlc3QgZnJvbSBBUEkgd2l0aCB0eHQgZmlsZSBhdHRhY2hlZCAgOikp"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @DaveEP I wasn't able to find a solution to change the sender name, But we ended up creating 3 different accounts on Azure AD with some additional configuration to send emails **on behalf** of the original email address, using its credentials each time. So we did not need to reAuthenticate it, an additional JSON was added to the original one: `"from": {  "emailAddress": { "name" :"test country A", "address": "testA@domain.com"   } }`

Comment: Thanks.  Can you be more specific about what was created?   I opened a new question here.  Perhaps that may be a good place to answer.?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64891817/microsoft-graph-send-from-shared-email-box-with-different-user-names

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) for the `sender` property:

> The account that is actually used to generate the message. In most cases, this value is the same as the from property. **You can set this property to a different value** when sending a message from a **shared mailbox**, for a **shared calendar**, or as a **delegate**. **In any case, the value must correspond to the actual mailbox used**.

and for the `from` property:

> The owner of the mailbox from which the message is sent. In most cases, this value is the same as the sender property, except for **sharing** or **delegation** scenarios. **The value must correspond to the actual mailbox used**.

Answer to your question is that it's possible **only if you create additional mailbox**.